# Convert NSFileSystemSize to Gigabytes

Tags: floating-point, numbers, size

I need to convert NSFileSystemSize to Gigabytes.

```
NSDictionary * fsAttributes = [ [NSFileManager defaultManager]
       fileSystemAttributesAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
NSNumber *totalSize = [fsAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize];
NSString *sizeInGB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n %3.2f GB",[totalSize floatValue] / 107374824];

//returns 69.86 GB
```

any ideas why it doesnt return at leat 8.0GB's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a nit, `1024 * 1024 * 1024` is `1073741824`, not `107374824` (you're missing a 1 in the thousands place.)

Comment: Nice catch. I actually went with: 
    NSString *sizeInGB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%.2f GB",[totalSize floatValue] / 1024 / 1024 / 1024]; seems to have worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)formattedFileSize:(unsigned long long)size
{
    NSString *formattedStr = nil;
    if (size == 0)
        formattedStr = @"Empty";
    else
        if (size > 0 && size < 1024)
            formattedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qu bytes", size];
        else
            if (size >= 1024 && size < pow(1024, 2))
                formattedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f KB", (size / 1024.)];
            else
            if (size >= pow(1024, 2) && size < pow(1024, 3))
                formattedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f MB", (size / pow(1024, 2))];
            else
                if (size >= pow(1024, 3))
                    formattedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f GB", (size / pow(1024, 3))];

    return formattedStr;
}
```